# Google Bigquery: Not adding data. No errors

Tags: google-apps-script, google-bigquery

I had a bigquery table that I was adding data to regularly over the past few months. Yesterday I created a new table in the same dataset to handle some other data. However, when I tried adding data, nothing happened.

I am adding the data using the function "BigQuery.Tabledata.insertAll" in a script I made and the response I get is "{kind=bigquery#tableDataInsertAllResponse}", which is suppossed to mean that there were no errors. When I queried `SELECT * FROM [<MyDataSet>.<MyTableID>]` the table in the UI, it said there were 0 results.

Soon after, I also noticed that the original table wasn't getting any new data. I tried deleting the new table I made but that hasn't fixed it.

The scripts are still working properly and I know the JSON is in the correct format. I even tried adding one row with one field at a time and that didn't work. `{kind=bigquery#tableDataInsertAllRequest, rows=[{json={tranID=3427412}, insertId=row3427413}]}`

Anyone encountered this problem?

Also this is my first time posting here so if I didn't follow the rules or provide enough information please let me know.

Thanks

Comment: There is an incident causing delayed appearance of streamed data.  Report here https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/bigquery-downtime-notify/O9di3uJPlqU/vsq1DiUI8bQJ. You can subscribe to this list for further announcements.

Comment: Thanks, I think that's what the problem is.